# Visualizing Collatz Graph using igraph

Tags: r, layout, igraph

I´ve recently looked into the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and tried to come up with a method to compute the vector for a given number leading to 1 and to visualize multiple of these vectors at once. However, I can´t figure out how to come up with a good layout for the graph. Ideally, I would like to have a graph like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Collatz-graph-20-iterations.svg), or like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Collatz-graph-all-30-no27.svg).

here´s what I do:

1) Function to compute the Collatz values

```
Collatz <- function(x){

    # checking whether the number is a mathematical integer
    if(round(x) != x){

            warning("x must be an integer larger than 1")
            break
    }

    # initializing output vector
    vec <- integer()
    vec[1] <- x

    # checking whether the input is valid
    if(x > 0){

            # continuing computation until we get a 1 in the vector
            while( 1 %in% vec == FALSE){

                    # when the last element of the vector is even
                    if(vec[length(vec)] %% 2 == 0){

                            # initilaize a new element in vec by dividing the previous one by 2
                            vec[length(vec)+1] <- vec[length(vec)]/2

                    }

                    # when the last element of the vector is odd
                    if(vec[length(vec)] %% 2 != 0){

                            # initilaize a new element in vec by multiplying the previous one with 3 and adding 1
                            vec[length(vec)+1] <- 3*vec[length(vec)]+1
                    }

            }   

    } else(warning("x must be an integer larger than 1"))

    # returning output vector except for the last element (which will be 4 insted of 1 due to the while loop)
    return(vec[-length(vec)])
}
```

2) Function to create a graph for all vectors in a set range

```
CollatzGraphing <- function(x){

    # loading igraph library
    library(igraph)

    Numbers <- 1:x
    List <- sapply(Numbers,Collatz)

    # sorting list by length and removing empty lists
    x <- List[order(sapply(List,length),decreasing=T)]
    x <- x[sapply(x,length) >= 2]

    # transforming the vectors into graph format
    x <- lapply(x, rep, each = 2)
    x <- lapply(x, function(y){y[-c(1,length(y))]})
    x <- lapply(x, function(y){as.character(y)})

    # transforming the prepared vectors into graph objects
    x <- lapply(x, graph, directed=TRUE)

    # creating a union of all graph objects
    CompleteGraph <- do.call(union, x)

    # plotting graph
    Plot <- plot(CompleteGraph,
                 vertex.size = 5,
                 edge.arrow.size=.1,
                 vertex.label.cex = 0.5,
                 vertex.color = "white")

    # returning graph object
    return(CompleteGraph)

}
```

When I use the second function without speciyfing any layout, I get something like this:

```
Graph1 <- CollatzGraphing(20)
```

[image: graph]

when I try to use a different layout the graph looks very different than from what I was aiming for

```
V(Graph1)
plot(Graph1,
        vertex.size = 5,
        edge.arrow.size=.1,
        vertex.label.cex = 0.5,
        vertex.color = "white",
        layout = layout_as_tree(Graph1, circular = TRUE, root = 21))
```

[image]

Is there a layout in igraph that would create a similar structure as the ones I linked in the beginning?

Comment: The second example you linked looks a lot like it was made with `graphviz`.  I don't use R, but graphviz is pretty popular and I would assume that there are bindings to it in R. igraph (at least in python) has some support to writing dot files, which is the format that graphviz uses.